# How I write most appropriately these queries into single statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write appropriately below queries into a single statement.

- "**CoverPageID**" is primary key column into CoverPageOthersCosts
  table.
- "**CoverPageID**" is primary key column into CoverPages.
- "**OurFileNo**" column is foreign key column into CoverPages table.

---

```
SELECT SUM(o.OutPrice) AS ShareOnSaving
FROM CoverPageOthersCosts AS o WITH
    INNER JOIN CoverPages AS c WITH ON o.CoverPageID = c.CoverPageID
WHERE c.OurFileNo = @OurFileNo AND o.DescID IN (1, 2, 3)

SELECT SUM(o.OutPrice) AS CommunicationCost
FROM CoverPageOthersCosts AS o WITH
    INNER JOIN CoverPages AS c WITH ON o.CoverPageID = c.CoverPageID
WHERE c.OurFileNo = @OurFileNo AND o.DescID = 6

SELECT SUM(o.OutPrice) AS HandlingFee
FROM CoverPageOthersCosts AS o WITH
    INNER JOIN CoverPages AS c WITH ON o.CoverPageID = c.CoverPageID
WHERE c.OurFileNo = @OurFileNo AND o.DescID IN (7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.DescID IN (1,2,3) THEN o.OutPrice END) AS ShareOnSaving,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.DescID = 6        THEN o.OutPrice END) AS CommunicationCost,
    SUM(CASE WHEN o.DescID IN (7,8,9) THEN o.OutPrice END) AS HandlingFee
FROM CoverPageOthersCosts o
INNER JOIN CoverPages c
    ON o.CoverPageID = c.CoverPageID
WHERE
    c.OurFileNol = @OurFileNo;
```

We can compute each of your three sums at the same time, in a single pass over the table, using `CASE` expressions.  Note that you might actually get better performance by doing each sum separately though.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to achieve this will be to add a case like this

```
SELECT 
  SUM(
      CASE WHEN o.DescID IN (1, 2, 3) THEN o.OutPrice ELSE 0 END
      ) AS ShareOnSaving,
  SUM(CASE WHEN o.DescID 6 THEN o.OutPrice ELSE 0 END) AS CommunicationCost,
  SUM(CASE WHEN o.DescID IN (7, 8, 9) THEN o.OutPrice ELSE 0 END) AS HandlingFee
FROM CoverPageOthersCosts AS o WITH
    INNER JOIN CoverPages AS c WITH ON o.CoverPageID = c.CoverPageID
WHERE c.OurFileNo = @OurFileNo
```